# Is there a way to make VSCode always open Bash/Powershell in a full size tab on startup?

Tags: bash, powershell, visual-studio-code

For example, I really like to use Powershell in the full size window instead of just in the terminal at the bottom of the screen. Instead of having to click on the Powershell thing and drag it up into the window every time to get the full size, is there a way to configure VSCode via a settings.json or Preferences or something to start with this Powershell (or, similarly, Bash) window no matter what?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the window maximized you can add:

```
"workbench.panel.opensMaximized": "always"
```

To your settings.json file.

For auto-launching a terminal you will likely need an extension:

[Is it possible to have the Integrated Terminal open automatically on start of Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45957618/is-it-possible-to-have-the-integrated-terminal-open-automatically-on-start-of-vi)